# Can I change the primary category of my App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I have recently published a new app in the appstore. It was approved, but I am having a bit of trouble getting in to the top lists for the category (Entertainment). Is it it possible to change the category to a less "ambitious" category?

It doesnt look like I can do it in Itunes Connect, and the developer guide states that the information is "locked", yet i see other developers mentioning changing categories in web forums. Is it possible, an if so, can it only be done when publishing an update?

I am thankful for any insights into this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it when you publish an update.